# How to add a readmore option in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net with c#. 
I am displaying some data from a database table. A column of that table is contains the description for that particular record. I want to show the minimum description first and also want to add some sort of read more options (Like, "Read more. . . " or ". . . ").

How can i do this job?

Help shell highly appreciated. . .

Comment: You want to display it always or for few items in which text length is > some value?

Comment: Are you using webforms or mvc?

Comment: @Anuraj I want to display it always.

Comment: @RobCarroll using webforms

Comment: Do you want them to be able to click a read more and show the text or just shorten the existing description? If you want to show the text do you want to do it on a new page or same page via jquery?

Comment: first i want to shorten the description and when user click at the read more option then show the more description at the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code :

```
public static string ShortDescription(string Description)
    {
        string result = Description;
        if (result.Length > 50)
        {
            result = result.Substring(0, 50);
            result += "....";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and use above method:

```
<p>
  <%# ShortDescription(Eval("Description").ToString())%>
  <a href='ShowDescription.aspx?Id=<%# Eval("Id") %>'>Read more. . . </a>
</p>
```

Comment: you can put that in `DataBound` field in gridview.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery plugin - it was excellent for me - 
http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Answer (score 0):

For a pure client-side JavaScript solution you can hide part of the description in an invisible span:

```
This is the beginning 
<span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="this.nextSibling.style.display = this.nextSibling.style.display == 'none'? '': 'none'">...more...</span>
<span style="display:none">of a very very very very very very very very very very very very very long description</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J3Mxs/

Note that using this solution long description will display in the same cell as the original short one.